# posgtres - way to load 1gb of mock data into table programmatically

Tags: sql, postgresql, unit-testing

I don't have any mock db hence question:

Is there are way to create a 1gb of mock data programmatically/through query something like:

```
while table size < 1gb keep populating table ABC with 1
```

I would like to just run this query on each db server instead of moving around and uploading mock sql dump each time.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the one gigabyte important or would approximately one gigabyte be enough? You could approximate your data storage size for a table by looking at the columns and just generate n rows with dummy data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
create table abc (
    abc_id serial primary key,
    data int not null
);

create or replace function abc_fill(size int, chunk_size int default 100000)
    returns void
    language plpgsql
as $$
begin
    while pg_total_relation_size('abc')<size loop
        insert into abc (data)
            select 1 from generate_series(1,chunk_size);
    end loop;
end;
$$;

select abc_fill(1024*1024*1024);

select pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('abc'));
1025 MB

select count(*) from abc;
18300000
```